# neo4j find all nodes with matching properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a relatively large set of nodes, and I want to find all pairs of nodes that have matching property values, but I don't know or care in advance what the property value is.  This is basically an attempt to find duplicate nodes, but I can limit the definition of a duplicate to two or more nodes that have the same property value.

Any ideas how to proceed? Not finding any starting points in the neo4j docs.  I'm on 1.8.2 community edition.

**EDIT**
Sorry for not being clear in the initial question, but I'm talking about doing this through Cypher.

Answer (score 23):

Cypher to count values on a property, returning a collection of nodes as well:

```
start n=node(*)
where has(n.prop)
with n.prop as prop, collect(n) as nodelist, count(*) as count
where count > 1
return prop, nodelist, count;
```

Example on console: http://console.neo4j.org/r/k2s7aa

You can also do an index scan with the property like so (to avoid looking at nodes that don't have this property):
`start n=node:node_auto_index('prop:*') ...`

2.0 Cypher with a label Label:

```
match (n:Label)
with n.prop as prop, collect(n) as nodelist, count(*) as count
where count > 1
return prop, nodelist, count;
```

Update for 3.x: `has` was replaced by `exists`.

Comment: With Neo4j 2.0.0-M06, I get a syntax error telling me I need the () around the match pattern. Like: match (n:Label).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one who does which I think does whatever you want.

```
START n=node(*), m=node(*)
WHERE 
  HAS(n.name) AND HAS (m.name) AND 
  n.name=m.name AND 
  ID(n) <ID(m) 
RETURN n, m
```

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=xe6wmt

Both nodes should have a `name` property. `name` should be equal for both nodes and we only want one pair of the two possibilites which we get via the id comparison. Not sure about performance - please test.

Comment: I used it with the following update for Neo4J 4.1.3
MATCH n,m
WHERE 
  EXISTS(n.name) AND EXISTS(m.name) AND 
  n.name=m.name AND 
  ID(n) <ID(m) 
RETURN n, m

Answer (score 2):

What about the following approach:

- use [getAllNodes](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/tooling/GlobalGraphOperations.html#getAllNodes%28%29) to get an Iterable over all nodes.
- using [getPropertyKeys](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html#getPropertyKeys%28%29) and [getProperty(key)](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) build up a `java.util.Map` containing all properties for a node. Calculate the map's `hashCode()`
- build up a global `Map` using the hashCode as key and a set of `node.getId()` as values

This should give you the candidates for being duplicate. Be aware of the hashCode() semantics, there might be nodes with different properties mapping to the same hashCode.

Comment: Not using java as stated above. Also, I've got over 20,000 nodes; I was hoping for something more efficient than looping.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j 3.1.1

> HAS is no longer supported in Cypher, please use EXISTS instead.

If you want to find nodes with specific property, the Cyper is as follows:

```
MATCH (n:NodeLabel) where has(n.NodeProperty) return n
```

Answer (score 0):

The best/easiest option is to do something like a local `Map`. If you did something like this, you could create code like this:

```
GlobalGraphOperations ggo = GlobalGraphOperations.at(db);
Map<Object, Node> duplicateMap = new HashMap<Object, Node>();

for (Node node : ggo.getAllNodes()) {
    Object propertyValue = node.getProperty("property");
    Node existingNode = duplicateMap.get(propertyValue);
    if (existingNode == null) {
        duplicateMap.put(propertyValue, node);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Duplicate Node. First Node: " + existingNode + ", Second Node: " + node);
    }
}
```

This would print out a list. If you needed to do more, like remove these nodes, you could do something in the else.

Do you know the property name? Will this be multiple properties, or just duplicates of a single name/value pair? If you are doing multiple properties, just create a map for each property you have.

Comment: I do know the property name, but I'm trying to do this through cypher if possible, b/c I'm not using a java client and my consuming app is communicating w/ the server using the REST api and cypher queries.

Comment: The problem is you're going to have to use a loop, unless you have these nodes indexed on the property name. If you have them indexed, you can loop through each node and look into the index if there are more then 1 nodes returned for a given property.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an index on that property. Then for a given value retrieve all the nodes. The advantage is that you can also query for approximations of the value.

Comment: How would you use this?

Answer (score 0):

With Neo4j 3.3.4 you can simply do the following:

`MATCH (n) where EXISTS(n.propertyName) return n`

Simply change `propertyName` to whatever property you are looking to find.