# Find Nodes with the same properties in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two datasets in Neo4J. I would like to find all nodes within these two datasets that have the same particular property. This is using Cypher code.

I am currently using:

```
MATCH n=node(*), m=node(*)
WHERE (n.name) AND (m.name) AND 
  n.name=m.name 
RETURN n, m
```

In the hope to get a result showing all nodes with the same `name`.

I am aware of this old 2013 post here: [neo4j find all nodes with matching properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818710/neo4j-find-all-nodes-with-matching-properties)

But the Cypher code has been significantly updated since this date.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Post a runnable, concise code example and explain what it does and what you think it should do.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output, along with what the current code provides and why that is incorrect for your situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no tables in Neo4j

```
create index on :LabelA(propertyA);
create index on :LabelB(propertyB);

MATCH (a:LabelA)
MATCH (b:LabelB)
WHERE b.propertyB = a.propertyA
RETURN a,b;
```

Comment: Don't think in relational. `MATCH (a:LabelA) MATCH(b:LabelB {propertyB: a.propertyA}) RETURN a,b;`

Comment: @ADTC this is the same as above cause query analyzer will rewrite it with WHERE clause.